# How convert mp3 to wave with n audio whit out save it to hard disk?

Tags: c#, naudio

How convert mp3 to wave with n audio whit out save it to hard disk? i saw this sample

```
public static void Mp3ToWav(string mp3File, string outputFile)
{
    using (Mp3FileReader reader = new Mp3FileReader(mp3File))
    {
        WaveFileWriter.CreateWaveFile(outputFile, reader);
    }
}
```

but it save the resualt in hard disk!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`CreateWaveFile` creates a WAV file. If you just want raw PCM, call `reader.Read` until it returns no more data. If you want an in-memory WAV file, then use the constructor of `WaveFileWriter` that takes a Stream and write into that.

Answer (score 0):

I research your problem and yet more answers.Try this articles:

1. http://hintdesk.com/c-mp3wav-converter-with-lamenaudio/
2. http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/8544/Aumplib-C-Namespace-And-Classes-For-Audio-Conversi
3. http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/Vsexpressvcs/thread/7039cada-8884-49a8-8fe5-9e4fc0b87b40/